# Recognizing other apps on my app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, twitter, ios6

i am developing an app,which needs to recognize all other apps which are installed on my iphone. Suppose,when i install my app,then it must recognize those apps which are allready installed(e.g Facebook,Twitter etc) in my phone and it must provide notifications of those apps in my app.If someone can provide idea on how to do this,that will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to enumerate all the apps on device. The only thing you can do is to check if there is some application with known URL scheme using [canOpenUrl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL%3a)

Here is the [list](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) of some url schemes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will give you all currently running processes you can distinguish the system processes and 3rd party apps via their process ids, but I am not sure apple will allow this or not, if you are further planning to upload the app on store. Code taken from forrst.com/posts/UIDevice_Category_For_Processes-h1H

```
- (NSArray *)runningProcesses {

int mib[4] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0};
size_t miblen = 4;

size_t size;
int st = sysctl(mib, miblen, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);

struct kinfo_proc * process = NULL;
struct kinfo_proc * newprocess = NULL;

do {

    size += size / 10;
    newprocess = realloc(process, size);

    if (!newprocess){

        if (process){
            free(process);
        }

        return nil;
    }

    process = newprocess;
    st = sysctl(mib, miblen, process, &size, NULL, 0);

} while (st == -1 && errno == ENOMEM);

if (st == 0){

    if (size % sizeof(struct kinfo_proc) == 0){
        int nprocess = size / sizeof(struct kinfo_proc);

        if (nprocess){

            NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for (int i = nprocess - 1; i >= 0; i--){

                NSString * processID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", process[i].kp_proc.p_pid];
                NSString * processName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", process[i].kp_proc.p_comm];

                NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:processID, processName, nil] 
                                                                    forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ProcessID", @"ProcessName", nil]];
                [processID release];
                [processName release];
                [array addObject:dict];
                [dict release];
            }

            free(process);
            return [array autorelease];
        }
    }
}

return nil;
```

}:

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [iHasApp library](https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp) for this.

The iHasApp iOS Framework allows you to detect installed apps on a user's device.
Detection results can be in the form of an array of detected appIds, or an array of appDictionaries from the iTunes Search API.